# How would medieval warfare be different when society & armies are led by intelligent dragons?

Tags: military, dragons

So here's the parameters: The society is a feudal one where a noble/aristocratic class of dragons rules over humanity, who are legally, culturally, & religiously bound to the dragons' service. Humans *can* become favored servants/courtiers/officers, or even viceroys & military officers, but will always be a servant to their liege dragon.

The dragons themselves are very sexually dimorphic. Males typically measure ~15 meters tailtip-to-snout, while females are much larger (and more physically powerful) at ~40 meters. Both sexes are capable of flight, have scales stronger than steel, and can breathe an incendiary substance identical to napalm. While their napalm is identical, females can launch a much greater volume of it at longer ranges than than the males. Females have a natural lifespan of around a millenium while males live ~500 years. Males are also more common, since females lay clutches of ~6 male eggs every few decades but only 1 female egg approximately every century.

Socially & structurally the dragons are matriarchal. Females typically being queens and empresses with multiple husbands/mates. Landed males rule smaller territories under the queens, akin to dukes & barons.

The tech is late medieval, equivalent to Europe in the 1400s. The dragons collect tribute from their human serfs primarily in gold for the hoards & meats for their carnivorous diet. Farming is skewed more towards livestock to meet the demands of the latter, with vast ranches of cattle & other large livestock being common.

Basically my question is how would warfare, how/when it's fought, how armies are structured, etc. change under these conditions? Would human armies remain relevant to warfare & if so, how?

Comment: Who are they at war with, and does that side have dragons in equal force?

Comment: The dragons fight among each other for many of the same territorial, idiological, & other reasons humans would.

Comment: How many dragons per castle are we talking? Does one dragon rule over a dozen villages, or does a single mid-sized hamlet have a ruling group of a dozen dragons? Essentially, how much do the dragons need the humans to do their dirty-work? What's the ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cold War Brinkmanship/Diplomacy

Your dragons are relatively powerful, as mentioned by the other answers, so they're certainly stronger than a human army on its own, but there is a bit of a problem.

> Females have a natural lifespan of around a millenium while males live ~500 years. Males are also more common, since females lay clutches of ~6 male eggs every few decades but only 1 female egg approximately every century.

That indicates an entire possibility that a Dragon Queen is a major target for any other Dragon Queen, since if you defeat them, either by subterfuge or by defeating them in honorable combat, it wouldn't take long for one Dragon Tribe to eventually find themselves effectively annulled by means of not having a female dragon who can lay another female egg within a century. Best case scenario, you end up [with a comedic story about a Dragon Princess not acting like she was next in line to ascend to the Dragon Queen/Empress role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Diaries_(film)), but that also gives large amounts of power to intermediate regents as a result.

In a situation like that, the dragons will likely advance up to and through [Peace of Westphalia style treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_of_Westphalia) just to avoid further bloodshed, and likely leading to a League of Nations/United Nations approach of resolving conflicts by diplomatic means well before they get to a point where they actually get to a warring state.

All factions would be agreeing to this (Well, except possibly the human slaves themselves, but they would likely be held in line by the dragons' ability to enforce said peace) due to the sheer fear of what would happen if they were invaded by a different Dragon Queen.

### This said, it's not like they wouldn't posture for war

So, let's say that Nation X sends a messenger to the Dragon UN to try and claim more land from Nation Y as part of a dispute over resources on some bordering island I.

As they're doing that, they may send some of their male dragons to the island I, perhaps in pairs of 2, carrying entire makeshift crates of human soldiers, armed up with equipment to both fight enemy dragons, and enemy humans.

Then they just wait there and effectively siege the island (Or if there's a non-island territory being disputed, just surround the territory that is being disputed)  while they wait to receive an update from the Dragon UN messenger as to the results of the dispute, and either occupy the island, or leave it, if it's determined during the treaty that Nation Y responded by effectively doing the same with equal or more force at island J, and they managed to get a concession out of the original invader, evacuate and leave.

If Nation Y doesn't necessarily want to occupy island J instead, and go to island I to confront Nation X, they would likely still be mostly about declaring stakes, and essentially boasting about the size and strength of an army they brought to the area to act as "muscle" for the negotiations on the treaty side.

This would likely be followed by a lot of public relations by both nations as to the motives of the opposing nation, and as to why they deserve the territory.

Ultimately, this would have a much larger effect on which dragon tribes have more territory based on which tribes have the better luck at having more spare Queens lined up in case of an disagreement leading to an actual fight, or how many male dragons a tribe can spare for these brinkmanship fights along with their human slaves to justify the other side capitulating to their demands - but full-on skirmishes, and outright wars, would likely be very rare, and would only come due to a large portion of diplomatic means breaking down, combined with dragon nations that are willing to risk lower level female dragons due to having enough female dragons to safely have a Dragon Queen buffer in case of a succession crisis due to the conflict getting beyond regularly heated. That said, even in those cases, a Dragon Queen might be trying to secure exit strategies should the battle turn against their favor quickly on a field of battle - because once the fight begins, the other side might just press their advantage to prevent the attacking nation from attacking them again in the future.

Comment: Don't forget duelling (to kill off troublesome excess males and provide excuses for territory seizure) and subterfuge (to secretly cause problems for opponents). Also consider the number of rulers you can support - if it's small enough, they'll form a pyramid government with nobody to oppose it. 500y is long enough for everyone to get to know everyone else...

Comment: I'd feel like dueling might actually be rather rare - the core problem being how often Dragon Queens are likely to produce a matriarchal heir. It's established that they lay about 1 Dragon Queen-able egg every century, but that may be on average, and there`s a possibility a century is skipped, or that a current Dragon Queen is unable to produce another Dragon Queen at all. Given subterfuge, they're more likely to temporarily exile excess Dragon Males to raise Dragon Queen candidates to maturity outside reach of hostile forces. More Dragon Males help with posturing for war otherwise.

Comment: Or, if they did have dueling, it would be to first blood, and very much non-lethal. Every century would have more than 6 Male Dragons (Possibly 12, maybe even 30 in a year reflecting a 500-year old situation where a Dragon Queen was laying clutches of eggs repeatedly just to try and get a Dragon Queen heir) likely to die from old age, so you'll want more around so that the New Dragon Queen has options (Or betrothal options for other nations' New Dragon Queens)  in early maturity, or just posturing guards if before maturity.

Answer (score 6):

**Humans would not make large scale war.**

The dragons would not allow it.  It would be like allowing herds of domestic animals to fight.  Wasteful.  Humans fighting means disruption of agriculture which means less food for dragons and humans.  Humans need to put their energy into agriculture, animal husbandry and mining.

Large scale human battles would be stopped by the relevant dragons who had property at risk.  Disputes between dragons would be sorted out between dragons in their own manner, with humans tangentially involved if at all.

Humans would definitely still scheme against each other, and make alliances, and break alliances and do all those things in the human repetoire.  Stuff like that which is below the radar of the dragons is of little interest to them.

Answer (score 4):

EVERYTHING would be completely different. It would hardly be recognizable.

Just like the rest of society would be completely different.

Let's make the fairly safe assumption that the dragons are not stupid.

Therefore, dragons understand perfectly well that *many humans cannot be trusted with weapons* regardless of how "bound" they seem to be. Those primates will inevitably turn those weapons against their dragon masters.

Therefore, in turn, the bulk of combat power will be dragon-controlled; perhaps even dragon-operated. Humans will occupy supporting, reserve, and auxiliary roles.

For example, you can protect fortresses with powerful arbalests capable of shooting down a flying dragon...but those arbalests will be assembled in dragon workshops, and firmly controlled by dragons crew-chiefs. Their construction and operation must be tightly-held secret from the auxiliary humans who move and reload and wind them.

Human archery won't be needed since dragons have the literal capability to place *fire* anywhere they wish. Indeed, bows may be registered or licensed, limited to hunters, and powerful bows banned. Dragons may keep their own version of a crossbow, of course.

Human cavalry won't be needed since flying scouts can range farther and faster. And dragons likely don't want how-to-fight-on-a-horse skills taught to humans. Horses will still be essential for transport and labor and dragon-food (yum!), but fighting skills won't be taught.

Human infantry formations provide *mass* (and are essential to defending against cavalry)...but are slow and seem rather vulnerable to dragonfire. So classic infantry formations are gone. Instead, human infantry in combat looks a lot more modern, small team movement intended to use cover and concealment and surprise to close distance with the enemy until they reach melee range. Small unit movement can win some battles in the field, but it won't reliably capture an enemy stronghold. Instead, large formations are used to move massed troops to/from their fighting positions under air cover.

Ultimately, the increased defensive capability of dragon air and fire suggests more stalemates and successful defenses.

Answer (score 3):

**No Pitched Battles. Castles turn into underground bunkers.**

**Pitched battles** ala Troy, Braveheart, Lord of the Rings et cetera, disappear entirely. Your army has no defense against an arrow-proof dragon that can fly over and melt a bunch of your troops at once.

Even if you put a limit on how often the dragons can breath fire, keep in mind it can just fly away to rest and then come back. If it takes your army a week to march from your castle to my castle, that is a week's worth of being melted by a dragon. You will not keep morale for that long, when the troops know there is nothing they can do to protect themselves.

**Sieges** (far more common historically) will need to be modified. Castle walls are redundant when a dragon can easily carry its troops inside, a dozen at a time. However the castle still has one important defence -- it is fireproof and the dragon doesn't fit through the doors. That means the other aspects of the castle still work. For example narrow ramparts, turrets, and spiral staircases make it hard to fight your way into a castle, even after breaching the walls.

I see the castles being modified more like bunkers, with many underground tunnels to keep dragons out and to bottleneck enemy troops trying to get in.

Combine this with the ability of a dragon to fly behind enemy lines and hit any target any time, I imagine we get a situation similar to the modern world with aircraft, where the idea of a front line disappear entirely.

I predict the main military action will take place between the dragons themselves. Either by fighting each other directly, or by burninating each other's assets and humans. This destabilizes the human population, so they provide less tithes, thus weakening the enemy dragon when you eventually do decide to fight them. Of course it's a bad move to burninate their territory entirely, since then there's nothing left over when you kill them and take their land.

Comment: Agree 100%. I would add that communication and supply lines will also be different, since dragons can carry messages or material from place to place with impunity from armies. Stealth from enemy dragons will be important, and the human armies' primary role will be to track the locations of enemy dragons and keep the enemy from tracking their own dragons. Small, mobile scout squads will be very common.